# The caller was not authenticated by the service (wsDualHttpBinding)

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication

I don't require any sort of authentication, client and service won't be on the same machine and in different domains. When I try to connect to the service I get the following error.

> 'System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException' Additional
>   information: The caller was not authenticated by the service.

Hence I tried to turn off the security on service:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomDualBinding">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceWebRoleStockTrading.Service">
        <endpoint address="Service.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomDualBinding"
          contract="WCFServiceWebRoleStockTrading.IService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Now when I try to run the service on its own I get this error message:

> The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate
>   in ServiceCredentials.

But I don't need any security. Installing a service certificate means that I expect my clients to have installed the same certificate in order to authenticate, correct? This is not what I want though.

I am quite stuck on this, an advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found it. I found it difficult, getting it right with the WCF Config editor in Visual Studio. Best is to copy and paste this.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomDualBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceWebRoleStockTrading.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomDualBinding"
          contract="WCFServiceWebRoleStockTrading.IService" />
      </service>
    </services>
...
 </system.serviceModel>
```

In the client make sure to have this in your configuration:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://xxx.cloudapp.net/Service.svc");
WSDualHttpBinding wsd = new WSDualHttpBinding();
wsd.Security = new WSDualHttpSecurity() { Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None, Message = new MessageSecurityOverHttp() { ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None, NegotiateServiceCredential = false } };
EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(baseAddress);            

InstanceContext site = new InstanceContext(this);
_client = new ServiceClient(site, wsd, ea);
```